# Read push notification message without picking from the notification center

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to read push message when app is in background or killed and user tap on application icon(which has badge) instead from notification center.I have seen few  questions in stackoverflow regarding this, but non of them solve this problem,

Here is the scenario,

1. I receive a push message.
2. And then i ignore the message.
3. Next i launch the application by tapping icon which has badge(not from the notification center)
4. It won't call `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method.

As per iOS application life cycle, it'll run `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` when app launches, and next time it'll call `applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` methods. my question is how can i read all the push messages from above life cycle methods which i received previously and ignored?

I have already tried below snippet in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184309/get-push-notification-while-the-app-is-not-runing-iphone)) but i always get null as payload.

```
NSDictionary *pushNotificationPayload = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(pushNotificationPayload) {
        NSLog(@"Payload is not null");
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:pushNotificationPayload];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Payload is null");
    }
```

Any valuable answer appreciated, Thanks.

BTW, i use iOS 6

Comment: You can't. This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944024/ios-6-update-view-after-push-notification-was-received-but-app-was-closed/14944270#14944270). Read the answer there.